# How to count how many nearby same items are in a list

Tags: python

I have list of numbers and I want to count how many nearby same items there.
Then I want to create new list that will multiply the number of occurrences in the number itself.

for the list `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3]`
the output will be `[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3]`

```
def multiply_lst(lst):    
    new_lst = []    
    counter = 1    
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):  
        if lst[i] == lst[i+1]  
            counter+=1  
        else:  
            new_lst += lst[i]*(1*lst[i])  
        new_lst += [lst[i]]*(counter*lst[i])  
return new_lst
```

Comment: everything else is clear but why at the last 3 occurred 3 times?

Comment: 3*1.
3 appear once. so multiply 1 by 3.

Comment: then why in the middle 3 occurred only once?

Comment: then @xashru's answer gives the right output, for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be complex but you can reach your goal also by following this solution:

```
def multiply_lst(given_list):
    counter_list = []   # list to collect counter for each of the different numbers
    different_numbers_list = [given_list[0]]  # list collect each of the different numbers and add the first different number from given_list
    result_list = []  # list for the result
    count = 1   # set count to 1

    # loop through the given list
    for i in range(1, len(given_list)):
        # if current number and next number are same add 1 to count
        if given_list[i] == given_list[i-1]:
            count += 1
        # else the number to different_numbers_list and add the counter for the number to counter_list and then set count to 1
        else:
            different_numbers_list.append(given_list[i])
            counter_list.append(count)
            count = 1

    counter_list.append(count)  # add the last different number's count to the counter_list

    # finally add items from different_numbers_list, (item * items_counter from counter_list) times to result_list
    for i in range(len(different_numbers_list)):
        for j in range(counter_list[i]*different_numbers_list[i]):
            result_list.append(different_numbers_list[i])

    return result_list

lst = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3]    # given list
print(multiply_lst(lst))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just add to the list a new list contains a number `x` repeated `x` times.

```
def multiply_lst(lst):    
    new_list = []    
    for x in lst:
        new_list += [x] * x 
    return new_list  # returns [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3]
```